# Rubocop Lint/UselessAssignment offense not detected

Tags: ruby, variables, rubocop

With Ruby3.3.0 (rbenv global) and rubocop 1.60.2, I noticed that sometime 'useless assignements' are not detected. Below is an example where offense is detected for *foo*, but not for *bar*.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
foo = 93
foo = 900
foo == 14

bar = 93
bar = 900
[].each do
  bar == 14
end
```

```
cop_test.rb:2:1: W: [Correctable] Lint/UselessAssignment: Useless assignment to variable - foo.
foo = 93
^^^
cop_test.rb:4:5: W: [Correctable] Lint/Void: Operator == used in void context.
foo == 14
```

The 'not detected' code seems to be linked to the test of *bar* inside a useless each. Note also that both test of *foo/bar* are useless but it is only detected for *foo*.

I do not get it,because I suppose that when variable are assigned several time in a row with no code between, it should be detected as an offense.

So, is it some kind of rubopop bug or I'm missing something.

Comment: You're right, `bar = 93` should trigger a `Lint/UselessAssignment` just because of the subsequent `bar = 900`. (the variable isn't used in-between)

Comment: Seems worth reporting to [rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/issues)

Comment: It may be a bug, but remember that RuboCop is fundamentally a style guide. It is *not* meant to be relied on as a code quality tool, so don't rely on it for more than enforcing a given style. Programmers, not RuboCop, must ultimately decide which constructs are invalid. If that weren't true, RuboCop wouldn't allow inline overrides.